# Difference in element height between Chrome and Safari rendering

Tags: html, css

[image]

In the above image, Chrome is on the left and Safari is to the right. The `wrapper` (green) element in my code is being rendered with different heights in Chrome and Safari.

Other similar questions on stackoverflow direct to this [stackoverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644245/2619658). I applied the solution given there and added specific heights to all elements and made them `display: flex`.

What do I need to do to make the `wrapper` element to be rendered with the same height across Chrome and Safari ?

```css
.block, .level-1, .super-wrapper, .wrapper, .wrapper-initial, .initial {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.block {
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    height: 2em;
    width: 4em;
}
.level-1 {
    height: 3em;
}
.super-wrapper {
    height: 3em;
    font-size: 0.4em;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: #8fbc8f;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
}
.wrapper-initial {
    height: 2em;
}
.initial {
    height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="level-1">
        <div class="super-wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="wrapper-initial">
                    <div class="initial">X</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What are your expectations? Can you provide more info and screenshots of both chrome and safari behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in using `em` without unifying the base (resetting), if you checked the `computed` styles tab in DevTools, you'll find that `font-size: 0.4em;` is computed to different `px` values,

You don't want to use `px` and still want to use `em`? you just can add:

```
html {
  font-size: 16px; // or any value you want!
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.block, .level-1, .super-wrapper, .wrapper, .wrapper-initial, .initial {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.block {
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    height: 2em;
    width: 4em;
}
.level-1 {
    height: 3em;
}
.super-wrapper {
    height: 3em;
    font-size: 0.4em;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: #8fbc8f;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
}
.wrapper-initial {
    height: 2em;
}
.initial {
    height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="level-1">
        <div class="super-wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="wrapper-initial">
                    <div class="initial">X</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Safari and Chrome use different font sizes for your elements. When you use `em`, it scales to the current element's font size.

To fix your problem, make sure that the element's font size is the same in every browser, or use `rem` as a unit instead. `rem` always uses the root font size of the document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units